# ibm notes FT search query syntax

Tags: search, syntax, full-text-search, lotus-domino

I have a need to search the response documents in the domino view by the parent `unid`

I tried this `[$ref]="324BEC7DB47895DEC2258057002E6E98"` but don't work. The result is empty.

In my case, there's a concatenation of the couple `AND` and without `[$ref]="324BEC7DB47895DEC2258057002E6E98"` it works.

Any `[$ref]` syntax suggestions?!

Answer (score 2):

You can't search for $REF content.

Get all responses to your document and ftsearch the resulting NotesDocument Collection:

```
  Dim collection As NotesDocumentCollection
  Set collection = doc.Responses
  Call collection.FTSearch("your search query", 0)
```

It reduces the collection to documents matching the search query only.